# Getting a: Cannot read properties of null error in Javascript when adding an event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to check whether a user has added at least 8 characters in a password field and add some validation text if they've not but I'm getting this in my console:
script.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at script.js:13:17

I believe it relates to this line:

```
confirmPassword.addEventListener('change', checkPassword);
```

Full code:

```
let password = document.querySelector('#password');
let confirmPassword = document.querySelector('#confirm_password');
let passwordValidation = document.createElement('p');
let passwordValidationText = ''

passwordChecker => {
if (password.length <8) {
passwordValidationText === 'Please enter a password, longer than 8 characters';
password.appendChild(passwordValidation);
}
};

confirmPassword.addEventListener('change', passwordChecker);
```

And the input fields:

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password">
```

My thinking being I only want to validate when the user has finished typing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When does your script run? Could it be before the DOM has loaded?

Comment: The name of the function is `passwordChecker`, not `checkPassword`.

Comment: Please provide the whole HTML File. Maybe the script is loaded before the HTML itself.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar a typo just updated. Same issue applies.

Comment: Yes thank-you @user1599011 I added async to the script being called in html and it sorted that issue!

Comment: Check this line
 let confirmPassword = document.querySelector('#confirm_password');
100% your id is not rendered at the moment you try to get it i.e. your JS is called before html with id is rendered(also check is your id correct). Change order and lift up html render

Comment: Also same applies, thank-you@Shachar297

Comment: See the answers in the linked question.